# Why "quelle heure est-il" and not "est-elle"?

Tags: genre, interrogative

Given that "heure" is feminine, as indicated by the interrogative adjective "quelle", why is the expression "quelle heure est-il" and not "quelle heure est-elle"? Je ne comprends pas.

Answer (score 3):

Its because the response to the question "Quelle heure est-il ?" is "Il est midi", using the non finite form.

"Elle (est)" is never used for an impersonal expression. In the following examples, it can't replace "il".

> Il est temps de partir.
>
> Il est vraiment difficile de trouver un bon artisan aujourd’hui.